# Finding the covariance of two specific random variables $X$ and $Y$

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, covariance

Let there be some constant $c \in [0, 1]$ and let $X$ be some random variable with the mean $\mu$. For convenience we could say that $X \sim N(0, 1)$, but it can be any distribution with a defined mean. Now let $Y$ be another random variable so that samples from $Y$ are generated in the following way:

Sample $u$ from $U(0, 1)$ and $x$ from $X$. If $u<c$, return $x$, otherwise return $|\mu - x|$.

How do we find the joint probability distribution of $X$ and $Y$ so that we can calculate their covariance?

Comment: No need to find the joint distribution for $(X,Y)$.  You just need to compute $E[XY]$ and $E[Y]$ to form $Cov(X,Y) = E[XY]-E[X]E[Y]$.  To compute $E[Y]$ use the law of total expectation (conditioning on something convenient), same with $E[XY]$.  Can you finish?

Answer (score 1):

I preassume $0<c<1$ and independence where it concerns the samples.

Then $Y=XB+|\mu-X|C$ where $B$ has Bernoulli distribution with parameter $P(U<c)=c$, $B+C=1$ and $X$ and $B$ are independent. With bilinearity of $\text{Cov}$ we find:

$$\text{Cov}(X,Y)=\text{Cov}(X,XB+|\mu-X|C)=\text{Cov}(X,XB)+\text{Cov}(X,|\mu-X|C)$$

For the first term we find:

$\text{Cov}(X,XB)=\mathbb E[X^2B]-\mathbb EX\mathbb E[XB]=\mathbb EX^2\mathbb EB-(\mathbb EX)^2\mathbb EB=\text{Var}X\mathbb EB=c\text{Var}X$

For the second term we find likewise:

$\text{Cov}(X,|\mu-X|C)=(1-c)\text{Cov}(X,|\mu-X|)$

So for finding $\text{Cov}(X,Y)$ it is enough to find $\text{Var}(X)$ and $\text{Cov}(X,|\mu-X|)$.